# jquery-ui autocomplete: show a list of pair ID-Name in the dropdown list but with ID hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an asp.net app which consists of a master page and a web form with a master page.

Web form contains a label and a textbox:

```
Enter department name: <input type="text" value="" id="lstDepartments" />
```

I have implemented the jQuery autocomplete using jquery-ui. When user starts typing in the textbox I call a web api method using jquery ajax which search for department names containing the substring typed and finally it returns a JSON with the results with below structure:

```
[
   {
      DeptID: "83838383",
      Name: "DepartmentName_1"
   },
   {
      DeptID: "63343434",
      Name: "DepartmentName_2"
   },
   {
      DeptID: "3444555",
      Name: "DepartmentName_3"
   }
]
```

jQuery Ajax call is:

```
    function ConfigureAutocomplete() {
        $("#lstDepartments").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {                        
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://www.mycompany.es/MyWebapis/Departments/search/" + request.term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return { value: item}
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1 // minimum 1 character to start searching
        });
    }
```

The call to the web api method is going ok, it returns a JSON with above structure stated.

What I am trying to do now without success is below:

Now I am trying to show those DeptID-Name pairs contained in the JSON in the textbox, but I want to hide DeptID on the textbox, I mean, I only want to show Names. So for example if I type "department" in the textbox below should be displayed in it as a dropdown list:

```
DepartmentName_1
DepartmentName_2 
DepartmentName_3
```

Then, once user select one of them from that dropdown list, I need to call another web api using another jquery ajax call. When user selects one item of the dropdown list I want to get its corresponding ID and pass it to the web api method as a parameter in order to get detailed information of that department using its ID.

How can I do that things?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for jquery ui autocomplete. There is an event for selected item that you can use: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select. The "ui" parameter contains the value of the selected option, which you can use to pass it to the ajax call.